# Powering a li-ion battery from a TEG

Tags: current, battery-charging, low-power, supercapacitor, energy-harvesting

For a project, i would like to power a li-ion battery from a TEG.
For that, i use a step-up converter called LTC3109 developed by linear technology but it was limited in current. I intend to create a system with supercapacitors storing energy and after releasing all to charge the battery.
Is it a good idea?

[image: my system]

thank you in advance for your help.
And sorry for my English.

Comment: The LTC3109 won't cold start from 30 mV.

Comment: And exactly how much current can you TEG provide?

Comment: The starting of LTC3109 isn't a problem. I 've a good gradient. 
Exactly, Short-circuit current is 0.424mA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the super capacitors will result in extra losses as it is just an extra step in the process. You would also need to add a second circuit to control the charging process of your battery (whereas, when you go directly to the battery you can try and include that in your first step-up convertor). Charging the battery more slowly (in theory) also results in higher efficiency as you loos less energy to ohmic losses and the ESR of the battery.

Comment: Ok. Even if i use a circuit to control to control the charging process of your battery, the problem is the same isn't it ? My circuit delivers 30mA and consumes 300mA.